# QGIS processing does not support jpg

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, jpg, qgis-processing

I would like to work with the gdal functions provided in the processing toolbox. 
It is easy to call:

```
import processing
processing.alglist()
processing.runalg("gdalogr:warpreproject","/home/USER/.qgis2/python/plugins/qgis2leaf/test_data/src_img.tif","EPSG:4284","EPSG:4326",0,1,"","/home/USER/Desktop/export_image.img")
```

as an example. unfortunately I need jpg in the ouput or png. 
Is there any reason why I cannot save as jpg. I can use the warp or translate function in the GDAL toolbox with a jpg but it is hard for me to call it from within python.

Back to the question: Is there a support for jpg in the GDAL processing functions in QGIS?

Comment: No sure answers, but here's some info from the gdal website: http://www.gdal.org/frmt_jpeg.html

Comment: If the source file has transparency, it can not be saved in JPEG format, because jpeg does not support that.

Comment: @AndreJoost but the gdaltools can handle it...weird

Answer (score 1):

No, as JPG does not support the GDAL create option but only GDAL create copy:
you can check it using this code:

```
from osgeo import gdal
format = "Jpeg"
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName( format )
metadata = driver.GetMetadata()
if metadata.has_key(gdal.DCAP_CREATE) and metadata[gdal.DCAP_CREATE] == 'YES':
    print 'Driver %s supports Create() method.' % format
if metadata.has_key(gdal.DCAP_CREATECOPY) and metadata[gdal.DCAP_CREATECOPY] == 'YES':
    print 'Driver %s supports CreateCopy() method.' % format
```